# How to pivot dataframe by adding duplicate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe with duplicate values in what I want to be a unique identifier column. The other columns of the dataframe contain data that I want to preserve by creating new "duplicate" columns. For example, given the following dataframe:

```
sample_df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  test = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
  result = c(93, 88, 89, 73, 89, 71, 73, 73, 75)
)
sample_df

#   id test result
# 1  1    A     93
# 2  1    B     88
# 3  1    C     89
# 4  2    A     73
# 5  2    B     89
# 6  3    A     71
# 7  3    B     73
# 8  3    C     73
# 9  3    D     75
```

Is there a way to pivot this by adding new iterations of the non-id columns? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
#   id test1 result1 test2 result2 test3 result3 test4 result4
# 1  1     A      93     B      88     C      89  <NA>      NA
# 2  2     A      73     B      89  <NA>      NA  <NA>      NA
# 3  3     A      71     B      73     C      73     D      75
```

Where the maximum number of duplicates in the id column determines how many new iterations of the non-id columns are joined to the dataframe.

I've tried doing this with `tidyr::pivot_wider()` but with this function I've only been able to generate output columns based on the *values* of the columns (for example, returning `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` as the output columns rather than `test1`, `result1`, `test2`, `result2`, etc.). I may also just be lacking the proper terminology to find other sources for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an "observation number" column within each `id` and pass it to `names_from` in `pivot_wider()`:

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)

sample_df %>%
  mutate(obs = row_number(), .by = id) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    values_from = test:result, 
    names_from = obs, 
    names_sep = "",
    names_vary = "slowest"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
     id test1 result1 test2 result2 test3 result3 test4 result4
  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1     1 A          93 B          88 C          89 <NA>       NA
2     2 A          73 B          89 <NA>       NA <NA>       NA
3     3 A          71 B          73 C          73 D          75
```

Comment: I'm not getting the same result that you're showing here. For me your code is returning a 3 x 20 tibble where each column contains a single value (and the rest are NA).

Comment: Are you running the latest version of dplyr? If you’re < v1.1.0, the `.by` argument in `mutate()` won’t work and may cause the issue. So either update, or use `... %>% group_by(id) %>% ...` instead of `.by`.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R `reshape`.

```
reshape(sample_df, idvar='id', timevar='test', direction='wide', v.names=c('test', 'result'))
#   id test.A result.A test.B result.B test.C result.C test.D result.D
# 1  1      A       93      B       88      C       89   <NA>       NA
# 4  2      A       73      B       89   <NA>       NA   <NA>       NA
# 6  3      A       71      B       73      C       73      D       75
```